# How do i compare dates and sort data from an api in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I am working on a project using reactjs and i would like to display data from an api based on a date selected, if it matches a date from the array of objects on the api, display the number of objects that has that date.

I am able to compare just a single date so far (2020-11-07), it alerts that they are equal but not any other date, don't know what i seem to be doing wrong there. I also have a problem displaying the number of objects with the selected date.

This what I have done so far

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function DateSort() {

    const [sales, displaySales] = useState([])
    const [dates, setDates] = useState()

    const value_handler = (e) => {
        let value = e.target.value;
        var timestamp = new Date(value).getTime()
        setDates(timestamp)
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        async function fetchData() {
            const response = await fetch("http://206.189.124.254:9000/sales")
            const data = await response.json()
            let length = data.length
            displaySales(data)
        }
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    return (
        <>
            <div className="form-group col">
                <input type="date" onChange={value_handler}></input>
            </div>
            {
                sales.map(sales => {
                    let date = sales.date
                    let dateobject = new Date(date)
                    console.log(dateobject)
                    if (dateobject === dates)
                        alert("yesss")
                    {

                        return (
                            <>
                                <p> {length} </p>
                            </>
                        )
                    }
                })
            }
        </>
    )
}
export default DateSort
```

Will appreciate some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think your date comparison logic is not correct. This is how you can do, assuming you are not comparing the time and comparing only the dates

```js
const sales = [
  {
    "_id": "5fa6c32ce9a0f010733cfc02",
    "product_id": "5f77b78be9a0f010733cfa71",
    "date": 1604707200000,
    "unit_price": 15,
    "total_price": 225,
    "quantity": 15,
    "user_id": "5f83294ae9a0f010733cfb0f",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fa6c390e9a0f010733cfc03",
    "product_id": "5f7c0ab7e9a0f010733cfa78",
    "date": 1604707200000,
    "unit_price": 14,
    "total_price": 196,
    "quantity": 14,
    "user_id": "5f898eb5e9a0f010733cfb91",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "5fa6c43de9a0f010733cfc04",
    "product_id": "5f77b78be9a0f010733cfa71",
    "date": 1604707200000,
    "unit_price": 300,
    "total_price": 4200,
    "quantity": 14,
    "user_id": "5f7f992fe9a0f010733cfb06",
    "__v": 0
  }]
  
  
  const date = '2020-11-07';
  
  const matchingDates = sales.filter(sale => {

      const saleDate = new Date(sale.date);
      // ignoring the time
      saleDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
      
      return saleDate.getTime() === new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);
  })
  console.log(matchingDates)
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it worked perfectly, but i am also trying to display the number of objects that has the same date. After i map the data and it loops through, it should display just the number of records that has the selected date

Comment: Welcome. If this solution was helpful to you, could you upvote this solution.
For displaying, you can first filter the sales array based on the date then map the result to display.